# TypeError: query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to update the value of a table using Python MySql DB but getting this error.
`TypeError: query() argument 1 must be a string or read-only buffer, not tuple`.
And I am clueless what is wrong with my answer.

```
def id_of_unverifedUniversity():
    cur3.execute('select id from universities where verified=0 and deleted=0;')
    print "===================Unverififed University================"
    for row in cur3.fetchall():
        #cur3.execute('SELECT id FROM Users where universityId='+str(row['id']))
    print row['id']
    query = ('SELECT id FROM users where universityId = %s order by id asc limit 1' %(str(row['id'])))

    cur3.execute(query)
    result = cur3.fetchall()
    for y in result:
        if y['id']:
            print str(y['id'])
            print 'update query statred'
            query1 = ("""update universities set updatedBy = %s where id=%s""", (str(y['id']),str(row['id'])))
            cur3.execute(query1)
```

i am getting this error in query1

Answer (score 0):

In `query1` the operator `%` seems missed. Which is binding the variables into `str`

```
query1 = '''update `universities` set `updatedBy` = %s where `id`=%s''' % (str(y['id']),str(row['id']))
```

Comment: @Abi Waqas seems `%` operator is missed in `query1`, see it on updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong formatting for the string replacement in query1, although I'm more familiar with .format().

Try:

```
query1 = ("""update universities set updatedBy = {} where id={}""".format(str(y['id']),str(row['id'])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your *query1* is a tuple.

```
query1 = ("""update universities set updatedBy = %s where id=%s""", (str(y['id']),str(row['id'])))
```

I have some comments for you here:

1. Don't use triple quotes for one-line string.
2. Use **format** function
3. You don't need to cal **str** to call **str** method of your object. **format** or **%s** will do it for you - will not be superfluous method call.

So your code could be like this one:

```
query1 = "update universities set updatedBy = {} where id={}".format(y['id'], row['id'])
```